# rails activerecord 'where' search through array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hi I have a problem with search query, with 3 values (val1, val2, tags) from which one is an array(tags). I know that rails doesn`t support arrays but Postgres does, and I have  it installed.

I have a model action:

```
  def self.find_object(val1, val2, tags)
    if tags.blank?
      Object.where( val1: val1, val2: val2 ).to_a
    else
      Object.where( "val1 = ? and val2 = ? and tags = [?]", val1, val2, tags).to_a
    end
  end
```

But I get an error:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" LINE 1: ...HERE (val1 = 'Ziemia' and val2 = '1' and tags = ['Jadeit']... ^ : SELECT "objects".* FROM "objects" WHERE (val1 = 'Ziemia' and val2 = '1' and tags = ['Jadeit'])

My problem is that I don't know how to handle array search. In my test app, code like this >> `Student.where("hobby && ARRAY[?]", hobby)` where hobby was an array works, so this was my start in this example. I will be glad for any hints how to handle this :)

Edit: added error message

Comment: i think this `tags = [?]` should be `tags IN (?)`

Comment: Nope now I get error `ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension`

Comment: are your `tags` in an array format.?

Comment: Yes      `t.text :tags, array: true, default: []` << from my migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 syntax to create an array in PostgreSQL:

- `ARRAY[1,2,3]`
- `'{1,2,3}'`

So either of those will work :

```ruby
Object.where( "val1 = ? and val2 = ? and tags = ARRAY[?]", val1, val2, tags).to_a
# or
Object.where( "val1 = ? and val2 = ? and tags = '{?}'", val1, val2, tags).to_a
```

---

Note however that when using the `'{}'` syntax PostgreSQL expects strings to be in double quotes (instead of the usual single quotes), and as such using this syntax with string arrays and ActiveRecord will fail. I would suggest you always use the `ARRAY[]` syntax which should never fail.